# Moodle Create own Authentication plugin

Tags: php, moodle

I got a blank page in Manage Authentication in Site Administration, after I have made own plugin for authentication. I have followed instruction (step by step) in [Official Documentation](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Authentication_plugins#Interfacing_to_API.27s).

They said that after you have made directory inside auth folder, your name plugin will appear in the list of manage authentication plugin in site administrator. But I got a blank page. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Add more information. Check your logs and post the error log if such exist. What version of PHP is used and what OS?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do with any Moodle development is to turn [debugging](https://docs.moodle.org/en/Debugging) on. If you still don't get an error message, then 9/10 times the reason is the 'require_once' line at the very start of your code - make sure the number of directory traversals are correct.